# Convert a String of bytes into ASCII

Tags: java, android, sockets, byte

I'm connecting to a bluetooth device that answers to some parameters I send it, but as a response I read from a socket like this:

```
String data = dIn.readLine();
```

Where dIn is a:

```
DataInputStream dIn = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
```

The thing is that I receive the data, but it's a byte array read on a string. How can I convert that string that contains my byte array into a String with the correct hexadecimal values?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you give an example of the data you're receiving, and how you think it *should* look?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's unclear whether you're trying to *actually* decode a text string which you've got as a byte array, or whether you want a text representation (in hex) of arbitrary binary data. For the first you'd use:

```
String text = new String(data, 0, data.length, "ASCII");
```

For the second you could use something like [Apache Commons Codec](http://commons.apache.org/codec/):

```
String text = Hex.encodeHexString(data);
```

Comment: More or less this is what I needed... But not exactly.

Comment: @Sonhja: Ask a more specific question, get a more specific answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at String's [Format function](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29). If you specify the [format](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Formatter.html) as "%X", it will be returned as a hex string

You will have to iterate through the byte array to convert each, as the above function accepts only primitive numeric types.

Comment: %X for uppercase alpha chars or %x for lowercase alpha chars.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the `DataInputStream` in an [InputStreamReader](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html).

`DataInputStream.readLine()` is deprecated.